# How to append a string to a float list

Tags: python, list, append

I have following list

```
[163.0, 171.0, 401.0]
```

And I would like to covert this list into following format

```
[['category_a', 163.0], ['category_b', 171.0], ['chiplet_name', 401.0]]
```

I have the following data to help to achieve the goal:

```
print (float(r[cr]))  --> Which will print all the integer values (ex: 163.0)
print r[c] -->  Which will print all the string values (ex: category_a)
```

I tried the append function to achieve my goal as follows:

```
a= (float(r[cr]))

b= r[c]

print r[c], (float(r[cr]))
```

Printed `chiplet_name 401.0`

```
[['category_a', 163.0], ['category_b', 171.0], ['chiplet_name', 401.0]]
```

Comment: How are you getting more than one integer value from a single `float` call (`float(r[cr])`)?

Comment: What are `c`, `r`, `cr` in your example?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Its a for loop. So every time it run I will get values 163.0, 171.0, 401.0

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that matches your actual code structure?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `zip()` in a list comprehension:

```
A = ['category_a', 'category_b', 'chiplet_name']
B = [163.0, 171.0, 401.0]

answer = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(A, B)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[['category_a', 163.0], ['category_b', 171.0], ['chiplet_name', 401.0]]
```